# Linking Items in Sharepoint 2010 Lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

So i'll try and explain this as clearly as possible without it getting confusing.

I have 4 lists, items within each list belongs soleley to that list.

As the item in the first list is progressed through a proces it is given a new reference number and so a new item is generated in the second list under the new reference number, as the new item in the second list in progressed through the process it is given a new number and a new item is created in the the third list and so and so forth.

So far the items have a 1 to 1 relationship but only i know that, sharepoint doesnt tell me they are linked. But they can then have the situation where a list 1 item will be linked to 2 items in list 2 and they can be linked to 2 items in list 3 and so on and so forth.

Is it possible to create a calculated field against each item to show what it is referenced agianst in other lists?

For example - List 1 has Item 1, from Item 1 came two Items in List 2. So against Item 1 List 1 i would like a column that list the two item in list 2. and in list two against each of the two items a column that refernces item 1 from list 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference other lists in Calculated Columns.

However you can setup lookups between the lists (and these can be one to many lookups) so

List 1 <--- List 2 <--- List 3

For an example see the default tasks list and dependant tasks column.